# Which are the versions required for spree, alchemy_cms, alchemy-devise in alchemy_spree installation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree, alchemy-cms

Im using the following on the gem file for the alchemy_spree installation, but getting lot of version compatibility issues:

```
gem 'rails', '4.2.4'
gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.18' 
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'alchemy_cms', '~>3.2.0'
gem 'alchemy-devise', '~> 3.2.0'
gem 'spree', '3.0.4'
gem 'spree_gateway', github: 'spree/spree_gateway', branch: '3-0-stable'
gem 'spree_auth_devise', github: 'spree/spree_auth_devise', branch: '3-0-stable'
gem 'alchemy_spree', github: 'magiclabs/alchemy_spree', branch: 'master'
```

Please help on the compatibility issues, if possible, please upload a working gem file.

Answer (score 1):

The new official home of Alchemy and `alchemy_spree` is the [AlchemyCMS GitHub organisation](https://github.com/AlchemyCMS).

The Spree >= 3.0 support is in the `spree-3.0` branch.

So, your `Gemfile` needs to look like this:

```
# Gemfile
gem 'alchemy_spree', github: 'AlchemyCMS/alchemy_spree', branch: 'spree-3.0'
```

after running:

```
bundle update --source alchemy_spree
```

your should be good to go.